# How to Implement On the Fly Cryptography

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, encryption, cryptography

I'm working on a windows desktop application (WPF) written in C# that download some files from a server at each startup. These files play a huge role in making the application work.

I would like to protect the content of these files with some form of encryption such as AES. These files should remain encrypted even when they are read by the application. So I am looking for a way to decrypt the files on the fly when they are being accessed by the application. In other words, only the application could understand the files but if users open them with other programs, they will be encrypted still.

It would be great if you could share some ideas or articles about the implementations. Thanks!

**Edit 1:**
The application make use of **CefSharp** to browse the **HTML/JS/CSS files** that are downloaded from the server at each startup.

**Edit 2:** I'm trying to implement something like **TrueCrypt**.

**Edit 3:** I would like to how to do what TrueCrypt can do. It encrypts the files and the encrypted files can be opened by any program normally because it decrypts them on the fly whenever the file are opened. I need this because I want to protect the HTML/JS/CSS files loaded by my application's embedded browser (CefSharp).

Answer (score 2):

You need to realize that you *cannot* prevent users from accessing your unprotected files on an open platform like the PC. That is what DRM tries to achieve for decades now, however this goal is [unachievable](https://superuser.com/questions/14224/how-can-i-explain-why-drm-cannot-work) by definition.

The only thing you can do is to make it harder / more cumbersome to access the unprotected files, however in the end, if someone decides to put enough effort into circumventing your protection, she or he will always succeed.

For instance, you may obfuscate your source files (by dedicated obfuscators or simply by minimizing them), you can use some non-standard file encoding (reverse of base64) or you may use some kind of encryption method. Because you need to ship your key as well, any encryption method will do, no matter how secure or insecure it is.

Finally, as others have already mentioned, the crypto primitives are located in the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace. Note however that for security sensitive systems I would not recommend to use them directly, because there are many nuances and getting it right is actually quite hard. You should have a look at libraries like [SecurityDriven.Inferno](http://securitydriven.net/inferno/), which wrap the crypto primitives with secure defaults.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have edited my post a bit. Basically I'm trying to implement something like TrueCrypt. So it would be great that if you could share some steps or maybe share an article that teaches how to make something like TrueCrypt. I know very well about the futility of DRM and I will try my best to talk my client out of this but just out of curiosity, I would really love to know how to make something like TrueCrypt. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **[System.Security.Cryptography Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx)** of the .NET-Framework.
[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769741/Csharp-AES-bits-Encryption-Library-with-Salt) you'll find two examples you can use.

Note: First, you have to read the content of the file AS BYTES[] using a FileStream or [System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx). And you have to implement your KEY - which means it is hardcoded in your application and can be found using a decompiler! 
So, it is almost impossible to prevent the user from reading the data.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I have edited my post a bit. I think your answer is good but may not be applicable to my case...

Comment: @GordonLuvinsky Thomas is right.  It is impossible to prevent the user from reading the data.  You need server involvement.  This question gets asked nearly every day and receives the same response nearly every day.

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas said, using `System.Security.Cryptography` is the best way to encrypt data. However you'll need to include the cryptography keys in the client application and it is very easy for anyone with access to this application to extract the keys.

You're probably better off not wasting your time encrypting the files.